# Is A7RW a legal call sign?

Tags: united-states, legal

I've seen a reference to the callsign A7RW. I can't find it in the FCC database or by searching the ARRL. Is it a legitimate US callsign?

Answer (score 6):

A7RW would be the call sign of a ham in Qatar, rather than the United States.  The prefixes AA – AL are allocated to the United States.  So AA7RW, AB7RW, AC7RW, etc. up to AL7RW would be valid US call signs.

The FCC have certain call signs that they won't issue, like a call sign with a three-letter suffix starting with X (so I heard, can't find a source), such as AA7XWW.  I don't know that such a call sign could be called "illegal" though, because the rule might not be codified into law.  The FCC issues all call signs, so they could simply refuse a request for such a vanity call sign according to an internal rule that hasn't been publicized or made law.

Comment: "...like a call sign with a three-letter suffix starting with X". It certainly used to be the case, but ***IIRC*** there are now US callsigns that do. *X* used to be for experimental stations.

Comment: I read about the "three-letter suffix starting with X" alleged rule somewhere regarding the call sign KA0XTT, the fictitious call sign for Tim Allen's character in the TV show Last Man Standing.  The producers were allegedly careful to use a call sign that wouldn't be issued by the FCC.  I couldn't find the article that I remember reading though.

Comment: Okay. The bottom line is that you answered the OQ in the first paragraph. +1.

Comment: 2x3 call signs with the first lettter of the suffix As X and prefix W? are for experimental licences only, and no 2x3 call signs starting with A are issued to hams except for FEMA stations (AF?EMA)